# Re-init application laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.7

I have two websites in the one laravel app. Http requests have no problems: depending of domain app include different views, config and other. But commands and async jobs have problems. Default app create. I transmit parameter (domain), but can't re-init app. I do anything, but pathes are default.

```
$app = require DIR.'/../bootstrap/app.php'; $app->make(Kernel::class)->bootstrap();
```

I tried, but it not helped.

Tell me please how do it.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that it will be helpful for anybody. I wrote this helper:

```
/**
 * Init the application.
 *
 * @param string $domain
 * @return void
 */
function initApplication(string $domain = App::DOMAINS[App::DEFAULT_SUBDIR])
{
    if (function_exists('putenv')) {
        array_map('putenv', array_keys($_ENV));
    }
    $_SERVER = array_diff_key($_SERVER, $_ENV);
    $_ENV = [];

    global $app;

    $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] = $domain;
    $app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

    (new Dotenv\Loader($app->environmentFilePath()))->load();

    $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class)->bootstrap();
}
```

Comment: What is Dotenv and App::DOMAINS